# NodeJs Express Router Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm rewording this since I have figured out what the problem is, but I cant understand how its happening or how to resolve it.

Basically, in all of my routes I have to places where I am adding a DELETE route. The first is as follows

```
 app.route('/bi/clubs/:id')
    .post(authentication,clubController.getAll)
    .delete(authentication,clubController.deleteClub);
```

The second location is

```
 app.route('/bi/clubs/members')
    .post(authentication,memController.getAll)
    .delete(authentication,memController.deleteMember);
```

Whenever I call DELETE on the '/bi/clubs/members', express is actually routing that to '/bi/clubs/:id'. I have actually gone through and traced that this is occurring.

I can validate that I am not adding the route anywhere else in the app, and if I comment out the DELETE route on '/bi/clubs/id', then the second DELETE route will route properly.  If I don't comment it out, the call to DELETE '/bi/clubs/members' will route to '/bi/clubs/:id'.

The order in which I am setting the routes is just as above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what's the actual error that the server is throwing? You're not providing a  lot of details...

Comment: Thats just the issue. I am not even getting an error in my log files or anything. I am testing from postman and just getting INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. The funny thing is, if i change the route for the delete method to anything else, then it will work.

Comment: You really need to provide more info (What is `authentication`? Does `getAll` work? Have you run Express in [debugging mode](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html)?).

Comment: authentication is a user auth piece, which works. GetAll works. In fact, the funny thing is, if i take the above code and break it up so DELETE is on its own route as follows : app.route('/bi/participants/delete).delete(authentication, partController.deleteParticipant)  then it works fine.  The whole issue is that both the http methods are on one route, although as i mentioned this used to work perfectly before. I am have run in debug mode, it just breaks when it needs to call the controller on the call to DELETE.

Comment: Any advice ? Anyone ?

Comment: With so little information we'd be just making blind guesses..try to break down your app to the minimum amount of code you need for reproducing this and post it then.

Comment: I've tried updated the original post. I hope that helps. The original code is too big to post on here.

Comment: you'll need to cut it down and create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - see this link for help http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I get what you are asking John. I have run into this before. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is matching your route `/bi/clubs/members`as `/bi/clubs/:id`. When a request is made to an Express app your app will start at the top of your routes and middleware and work its way down to the end hitting all the routes that it matches.

When you tell Express to match the route `/bi/clubs/:id`, all you are telling it is match `bi`, then `clubs` and then a dynamic value that you are referring to as `id`. Although you are probably looking for `id` to be a number or a MongoDB ID, Express doesn't know the difference, so technically the string `members` matches as a dynamic value. Just not the one you want.

If you `console.log` the value of `id` it should be `members`. Your static routes need to be registered before your dynamic routes.

If you have any questions or would like an example please let me know.

Comment: Max, thanks a lot that makes sense. But I'm still not sure how to get around this issue without having to change my paths. Can you please provide an example. Or let me know if you need any further info re my code. I am using the MEANJS structure, and it is adding all of my routes im not sure in which order, and i have these 2 routes in different files.

Comment: @John how are you calling those route files? I assume with ```require()```. You just have to make sure that where ever you call or load your files, the file with ```/bi/clubs/members``` comes first. If that does not make sense please let me know and I will provide a clear example.

Comment: You could test out @Johns theory, using regular expressions for your routes.

Comment: @AfDev, that seems unnecessary since Express is already doing the matching. He just needs to order his routes correctly.

Comment: Max, sorry for not responding earlier. But you were exactly right. Thank you very much !